# Storing data in a word file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an Excel file, that has around 800 rows and a couple of columns of data.
The word file has three drop-downs. The first dropdown has the data of one column. The content of the second dropdown depends on the selected data in dropdown 1, and dropdown 3 depends on dropdown 2.

I've already made a VBA script, that does this by reading from the excel file. My problem is, that I need to get rid of the excel file since I need to have the word file by itself.

How can I store 800 rows of excel data into a word file without the user being able to see it, and so that I can use it in VBA code.

I already looked into this:
https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-do-i-create-a-microsoft-word-database
But this just generates another file, which isn't much different from just having an excel file.

Comment: Look at the concept of Custom XML Parts (CustomXMLParts in the object model). Excel and PowerPoint have this, as well as Word BTW.

Comment: Awesome! This'll probably solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: OK, I'll write it up as an Answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word has limited capability for storing data. Before the introduction of the Open XML file format with Word 2007 the only possibility was to use "Document Variables" - a way to save string information. While it is possible to store data in character-delimited format, this is not advisable for such large amounts of data.

The Open XML file format introduced the concept of "Custom XML Parts" - XML files that can be stored within the ZIP file structure of an Office document. (Besides Word, Excel and PowerPoint also support Custom XML Parts).

A Custom XML Part can be accessed via the object model (`CustomXMLPart`) using standard XML tools (`MSXML` parser, for example) of any programming language that can interact on the COM level. It's also possible to access a Custom XML Part through the *closed* Office document's Open XML using any programming language that can work with ZIP packages.

A Custom XML Part is not visible to the user. In Word, only, the contents of a Custom XML Part can be linked (mapped) to content controls on the document surface. The content of a node will be displayed in the document; user edits will be written back to the XML and such mappings provide additional events on actions taken in content controls (validation, for example).

Currently, this is the recommended method to "embed" data in an Office document.